# Lead Tool Master Template Creation for Table

Tags: leadtools-sdk

How can I create Master Page Using Table Template ?
In My Case  I have one invoice document consist of two page (tiff file format),
so on my invoice document one large table occupied on both pages.so i want to create master page for same using Lead Tool master page form editor ..

Answer (score 0):

Jay,
The best approach depends on the exact case you have.
Do you have an invoice that might span 2 pages? If yes, you will likely have to combine the 2 pages to make a single long TIFF image and then process it against the master form.

On the other hand if you have a 2-page invoice, you will need to have 2 separate invoice forms.

If you're still not sure how to proceed, please send full details and some sample files to LEADTOOLS support.